# Future builder Constantly Updates

Tags: flutter, dart, filter, future

I am using a future builder to grab data from a snapshot and filter that data into another Future function that creates markers. I get the results from filtering the locations for all of the restaurants but, the function constantly updates and the data just flickers.

Edit 2: JSON Data

```html
    { restaurant:[  {
            "id": 4,
            "restaurant_name": "Good Chemistry",
            "phone": "1231231234",
            "street_address": "2 Penn Plaza",
            "restaurant_logo": "https://restaurants.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_logo/GOODCHEM-3-web_99314.jpg",
            "restaurant_photo": "https://restaurants.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_photo/GOODCHEM-3-web_99314.jpg",
            "city": "NY",
            "state": "New York",
            "zip_Code": 10010,
            "lat": 40.8931283,
            "lng": -73.8205375,
            "latlng": "(40.7770112244898, -74.2110798163265)",
            "opening_hours": [
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Tuesday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Wednesday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Thursday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Friday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Saturday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Sunday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": 7,
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                }
            ],
            "ratings": 4.1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "restaurant_name": "The Farmacy",
            "phone": "1231231234",
            "street_address": "11 Penn Plaza",
            "restaurant_logo": "https://restaurants.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_logo/farma.jpg",
            "restaurant_photo": "https://restaurants.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_photo/farma.jpg",
            "city": "NY",
            "state": "New York",
            "zip_Code": 10010,
            "lat": 40.8931283,
            "lng": -73.8205375,
            "latlng": "(40.7770112244898, -74.2110798163265)",
            "opening_hours": [
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Tuesday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Wednesday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Thursday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Friday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Saturday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Sunday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": 7,
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                }
            ],
            "ratings": 4.7
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "restaurant_name": "Hoboken Smokin",
            "phone": "123-123-1234",
            "street_address": "11 Penn Plaza",
            "restaurant_logo": "https://restaurants.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_logo/urban-restaurant-web-1024x640.jpg",
            "restaurant_photo": "https://restaurants.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_photo/urban-restaurant-web-1024x640.jpg",
            "city": "NY",
            "state": "New York",
            "zip_Code": 10010,
            "lat": 40.8931283,
            "lng": -73.8205375,
            "latlng": "(40.7770112244898, -74.2110798163265)",
            "opening_hours": [
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Tuesday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Wednesday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Thursday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Friday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Saturday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Sunday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": 7,
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                }
            ],
            "ratings": 3.5
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "restaurant_name": "The Bakeree",
            "phone": "1231231234",
            "street_address": "433 5th Ave",
            "restaurant_logo": "https://restaurants.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_logo/restaurantimage.jpeg",
            "restaurant_photo": "https://restaurants.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_photo/restaurantimage.jpeg",
            "city": "NY",
            "state": "New York",
            "zip_Code": 10016,
            "lat": 40.7512061,
            "lng": -73.9822721,
            "latlng": "(40.7770112244898, -74.2110798163265)",
            "opening_hours": [
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Tuesday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Wednesday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Thursday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Friday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Saturday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": "Sunday",
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "day_of_week": 7,
                    "opening_time": "08:00:00",
                    "closing_time": "22:00:00"
                }
            ],
            "ratings": 4.6
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT 1: _setRestaurant function

```html
Future getRestaurants() async {
  var url = 'http://yellows-1929.herokuapp.com/api/customer/restaurant/';

  var response = await http.get(url);
  var responseData = json.decode(response.body);

  Restaurants _restaurant = Restaurants.fromJSON(responseData);

  return _restaurant.restaurant;
}




Filter Location function

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Future builder that gets the data and calls the function filterMarker:

```html
Widget _buildRestaurants() {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              FutureBuilder(
                  future: _setRestaurants,
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    var restaurants = snapshot.data;
                    recRestaurants = snapshot.data;

                    if (snapshot.data == null) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    } else {
                          filterMarker(restaurants, 20);

                      return Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          _makeRestaurants(restaurants),
                          _buildCoupon(),
                          _buildVendors(filteredVenues)
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                  })
            ]));
  }
```

THe filter just constantly updates and prints

```html
flutter: the lat is 41.722068434324785 and the long is -74.34910777767849
flutter: There are 1 _filteredMarkers
flutter: There are 0 _filteredMarkers
flutter: There are 0 _filteredMarkers
flutter: There are 1 _filteredMarkers
flutter: There are 1 _filteredMarkers
flutter: There are 1 _filteredMarkers
flutter: There are 0 _filteredMarkers
flutter: There are 0 _filteredMarkers
flutter: There are 1 _filteredMarkers
```

Comment: Hey, could you please add the source code of the _setRestaurants future?

Comment: Added the function

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your getRestaurants function, I tried to get that url and heroku says "no such app"

Comment: It's CSRF protected. I'll update with the json output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell what's going on without a full code snippet - it'd be much more helpful if you created a small working sample that showed what was going on.

However, I believe there's a few things that might help.

1. Stop building widgets with functions wherever possible. If it's complex enough to need a function to build it, you should most likely be building it in a widget of its own. This allows flutter to optimize the building of different widgets as well as cleaning up your code.
2. It's unclear what `_setRestaurants` is, but you're referencing it in the FutureBuilder. The right away of doing this would be for `_setRestaurants` to be a Future, and have it only change **when a new server request is done**. Treat the `_setRestaurants` object as part of the state of the widget, and assume that when it changes the widget will be rebuilt. So that would look something like:

```
Future<Restaurants> _setRestaurants;

void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _setRestaurants = _getRestaurants();
}

void updateRestaurants() {
  setState(() {
    _setRestaurants = _getRestaurants();
  });
}
```

*Note that I don't actually recommend doing it that way exactly, this is just to demonstrate what the OP might be doing wrong*.

3. You probably shouldn't be filtering the data on the client side of things. Think about scale - if you have 50 restaurants it's sustainable I suppose, but if you have 1000s of them, you can't request them all each time. You should instead be adding parameters to the get request and filtering on the server.
4. It would make sense to split out the "retrieving information from server and filtering" part of this from the "displaying the restaurants on the screen" part of this. That way you'll have separation of concerns, you can test the server part and UI part independently, and it'll be more robust. There are many different ways to go about this so I'm not going to go in depth here as it's quite out of scope for this question, but look into MVVM or take a look through some of the links on the [Flutter State Management page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options). You could also use a StreamBuilder and stream instead of futurebuilder as that would allow for updated results to be shown each time the data is changed (i.e. when you change the filter).